# Sanitize environment with command or bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash shell, I want to sanitize the environment as the first thing when running with a command.

I want to unset all the environment variables and only set the ones that are critical for the shell to function, plus the ones the ones needed by my script to complete it's task.

Is there a way to do this in a simple and clean way?

Comment: In Bash, the `env` command has a flag `-i` which will clear all your environment variables to login default.  So run this:  `env -i bash`

Comment: That's not really "in bash" -- `env` is a standard UNIX command, not a bash builtin. You can invoke it without a shell at all (from C, from Python, etc).

Answer (score 60):

You can use `env` and a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
env -i /path/to/main_script.sh
```

From `man env`:

> ```
>    -i, --ignore-environment
>           start with an empty environment
> ```

You can also, of course, just run the script as `env -i script.sh` if you are running it by hand. Unfortunately as far as I can tell one can't use the script shebang to run `bash` through `env` like this; the shebang can only accept two parameters by definition as parsed by the kernel.

The other semi-reliable solution using `env` or `exec -c` (which does pretty much the same) that I can think of would be to use `exec -c $0` to re-run the script with a clean environment if you detect it's not clean. Assuming `$HOME` is set in an unclean environment and is not set in a clean one (that's true in my install):

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$HOME" != "" ] && exec -c $0
# rest of the script here
```

Comment: I like the `exec -c`.  At the cost of some brittleness you can strengthen it to: `[ "$(env | /bin/sed  -r -e '/^(PWD|SHLVL|_)=/d')" ] && exec -c $0`.  That is, it insists that everything be cleared except for a few things that bash seems to set automatically.

Comment: Note that by using `env -i` or `exec`, you will lose non-environment (i.e. non-exported) shell variables as well.

Comment: As for the shebang issue: coreutils’ `env` recently ([version 8.30, released in July 2018](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=NEWS#l176)) got an option `-S` which solves this issue: this option expects a string which is split on whitespaces to form the command to be called.
Thus, our shebang can be written `#!/bin/env -iS /bin/bash`.

This option even supports setting variables, so that we can preserve some variables, eg PATH and TERM: `#!/bin/env -iS PATH=${PATH} TERM=${TERM} /bin/bash`.

See [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/env).

Answer (score 17):

### Unset all environment variables bash linux

Command: `env -i bash`

**Example, create local and environment variables, then reset to defaults:**

```
el@defiant ~$ LOCAL_DOGE="such variable"
el@defiant ~$ ENVIRONMENT_DOGE="much code"
el@defiant ~$ export ENVIRONMENT_DOGE
el@defiant ~$ set | grep DOGE
ENVIRONMENT_DOGE='much code'
LOCAL_DOGE='such variable'
el@defiant ~$ env | grep DOGE
ENVIRONMENT_DOGE=much code
el@defiant ~$ env -i bash
el@defiant ~$ set | grep DOGE
el@defiant ~$ env | grep DOGE
el@defiant ~$
```

So wow, `LOCAL_DOGE` and `ENVIRONMENT_DOGE` are gone with one command.

### Unset all environment variables bash linux, alternate way.

```
env - /bin/bash
```

**Example:**

```
el@defiant ~$ DOGE1="one"
el@defiant ~$ export DOGE2="two"
el@defiant ~$ set | grep DOGE
DOGE1=one
DOGE2=two
el@defiant ~$ env | grep DOGE
DOGE2=two
el@defiant ~$ env - /bin/bash
el@defiant ~$ set | grep DOGE
el@defiant ~$ env | grep DOGE
```

Comment: This is NOT what the OP wants imho; or else at least not a correct answer. What you do here is just a new SUBSHELL without inheriting the old environment. If you do that a few times you'll run out of memory :p.

Comment: Agreed with Carlo, this is absolutely not a solution... it doesn't unset variables, it starts a new session.

Comment: @JDiPierro I wrote this answer before I understood that.  This answer received many upvotes because newbies hitting this stackoverflow artifact don't know how to uniquely identify terminal identities, and this at least shows them how to get a clue.  The proper followup question is: How does my operating system handle bash/zsh/shell startup sequence and shutdown sequence and how can I control it?  Cheatsheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sentientmachine/Cheatsheets/master/bash_cheatsheet.png

Answer (score 10):

This worked when I tried it:

```
for c in $(set | cut -d '=' -f 1); do unset $c; done
```

It spewed errors on the const variables, but I was able to ignore them.

Comment: I'd use `env` instead of `set`, as the latter prints also functions in bash).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to do this without starting a new shell, and that will work even with weird variable names (containing whitespace/newlines):

```
while IFS='=' read -rd '' name value ; do unset "$name" ; done < /proc/self/environ
```

The disadvantage is that it is Linux-specific, and relies on procfs being mounted.

This will unset *all* environment variables, even `HOME` and `PATH`. This may or may not be what you want.

Explanation: `/proc/PID/environ` contains the process's environment block, as a series of zero-delimited `NAME=VALUE` strings. We use a `read` loop, setting the field separator `IFS` to `=` so that we can split the name and value from each string. By setting the line delimiter (`-d`) to an empty string, we cause `read` to use the null character (the "first" character of a null-terminated string) to split lines. Then, just unset each name in turn (taking care to quote it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your statement is easily disproved with `env $'a\nb=c\nd' bash -c env` (bash 4.4.23(1)-release). Or did you mean something else?

Comment: ...okay, managed to trace down where I got that mistaken impression from. POSIX *permits* discarding such variables, but not all shells do so; what got it stuck in my head was misremembering the research associated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989263/why-cant-environment-variables-with-dashes-be-accessed-in-bash-4-1-2 -- see reference therein re: the discarding-variables-with-invalid-names-is-permitted assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Eduardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526956/eduardo-ivanec):

```
$ env -i bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "${?+?=$?}" "${#+#=$#}" "${*+*=$*}" "${@+@=$@}" "${-+-=$-}" "${!+!=$!}" "${_+_=$_}" "${$+$=$$}"; env'
?=0
#=0

-=hB

_=bash
$=26927
PWD=/home/username/INVENTORY
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env
```

In other words, the following variables are defined in a script run with `env -i` *and* shown by `env`:

- `$PWD` (working directory)
- `$SHLVL` (number of shells within shells)
- [`$_`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#UNDERSCOREREF) (final argument of previous command)

The following variables are *also* defined, but *not* shown by `env`:

- `$?` (result of last command)
- `$#` (number of arguments)
- `$-` (flags passed to the script)
- `$$` (PID of the script)

Comment: `env -i bash -c` is perfect! I get my default environment while cleaning all other stuff away, thx!

Comment: You don't need to save/restore `$?`, `$#` etc. These are not actually part of the environment - they are internal shell variables.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem while trying to make a helper function to avoid the proxy. I came to call it `proxyless`. Its code follows:

```
proxyless () {
  cmd=(unset http_proxy https_proxy \; ${@})
  bash -c "${cmd[*]}"
}
```

What I am doing effectively is building a command array to pass to bash. So, I use `unset` to do the obvious, and I put all the command arguments to the end of the array. So, for example,

```
$ proxyless curl google.com
```

will become (according to `bash -x`)

```
$ bash -c 'unset http_proxy https_proxy; curl google.com'
```

Comment: Doesn't handle whitespace properly. Try: `proxyless printf '%q\n' a b 'c d' $'e\nf'` and compare the output without `proxyless`.

Also, the question is how to remove *all* environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
for ENV in $(env | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'); do unset $ENV; done
```