# Run from clean login shell without credentials

Tags: linux, bash

So I've got an executable with conflicting dependencies with the build system it is running in. (AKA Xilinx doesn't play well with others). I'd love to run a cmake script as part of the build process, but it is depended on different dlls. I can try to figure out a version of cmake that matches the xylinx dlls. Xylinx redirects the dependencies to the different C++ runtimes by setting a bunch of environment variables.

[Sanitize environment with command or bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671027/sanitize-environment-with-command-or-bash-script)

Will completely clean out all environments, but what i really want to do is run the script after the .bash_rc or .bash_profile is called. (cmake seems to require some of that to be set, as `env -i cmake` returns an error) I'd like to do it without having to require the login credentials. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass environment variables directly in a command line, right before the executable name:

```
ENV_VAR=foo command -options ...
```

If you want to pass multiple variables just add them one after one:

```
ENV_VAR_FOO=foo ENV_VAR_BAR=bar command -options ...
```

In your case, you'll need to find out which environment variable `cmake` needs to access the libraries. Then pass this to the call, like:

```
LIB_PATH=/path/to/libs cmake -options ...
```