# Bash: how to unset an env variable with a hyphen (-)?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have in my environment some variables that have an invalid identifier. When I try to unset them, I get the following error:

```
$ unset A-B
bash: unset: `A-B': not a valid identifier
```

How to unset them?

Comment: [Why can't environment variables with dashes be accessed in bash 4.1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989263/why-cant-environment-variables-with-dashes-be-accessed-in-bash-4-1-2) is not an identical question, but it's liable to be of interest to people who find this one useful. :)

Comment: One way of getting into this trap: `env "foo-bar=baz" bash`

Comment: In what way does this become a problem, just out of curiosity?

Comment: When `bash` starts up, it looks in the environment for names that are valid identifiers, and creates shell variables initialized with those values. It correctly ignores (per the POSIX standard: "Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2017 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the <underscore> ( '_' ) from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; **applications shall tolerate the presence of such names**.") any names that aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to the answer by [Honza P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192315/honza-p):

According to `man bash` the environment variables have the form `name=value` where `name` consists only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and begins with an alphabetic character or an underscore. So the name `A-B` is an invalid variable identifier for Bash, and cannot be used or accessed because it has internal validations (enforced strongly in late Bash versions because of vulnerabilities in Bash itself). The only solution is starting another secondary sub-shell that not have the offending names using the utility `env` to erasing them before launching Bash:

```
env -u 'A-B' bash
```

Note that the single quotes aren't needed, but to me is more readable that way as indicates the text inside is a string, not other command.

If you have more variables simply list them separated by spaces, or if you want to run only an script without the variables you can use for example:

```
env -u 'A-B' 'OTHER-VAR' 'bad-name' bash -c 'myscript.sh arg1 arg2'
```

The subshell will run `myscript.sh` with the arguments `arg1` and `arg2`, and exit to the current Bash shell.

Consult the man page of 'env': [`man env`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution I guess but it worked in my case.

I tried an example by bishop `env -u "foo-bar=baz"`, then `env -u "foo-bar"` but this approach still left some garbage in variables e.g. `_=foo-bar`. So I used `unset _` and then it is gone.

Comment: `$_` is a [special bash variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) containing "the last argument to the previous simple command"; so there's no need to `unset` it; it's working exactly as intended.  But `env -u` doesn't answer the question, since it requires launching a subprocess. The question is about unsetting the environment variable in the current bash process.