# Transversal visibility of Bash's exported functions

Tags: bash, function, shell, environment-variables

I ran an experiment to see if a Bash's exported function was still visible with a different shell in-between the processes chain.

To my surprise the exported function is sometimes still visible.

I am looking for an explanation of how and why a Bash's specific exported function is maintained within the environment through different shells, whereas it is not a POSIX standard environment variable.

Somehow I have a clue that the exported function declaration is stored as a string within a (standard ?) environment variable. But how is it invisible as an environment variable to incompatible shells, and how is it maintained within the environment?

Here is my experiment code:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LANG=C

# Declare function and export it
fn(){ printf 'Hello World\n';}
export -f fn

# Standard usage, call exported function within a child bash
bash -c fn

# Available shells for tests
available_shells=()
for sh in ash bash dash ksh tcsh zsh
do
  if shell_path=$(command -v "$sh" 2> /dev/null)
  then
    available_shells+=("$shell_path")
    real_shell_path=$(realpath "$shell_path")
    shell_version=$(
      read -r pkg < <(apt-file search "${real_shell_path#/usr}" | awk -F: '{print $1}')
      dpkg -s "$pkg" | awk '/Version:/{print $2}'
    )
    printf 'Found: %s\tversion: %s\n' "$shell_path" "$shell_version"
  fi
done

# Test transversal visibility of exported fn through different shells
for sh in "${available_shells[@]}"; do
  printf "Testing %s -c 'bash -c fn':\\n" "$sh"
  "$sh" -c 'bash -c fn'
  printf \\n
done
```

The result on my system reveal that exported `fn` transversal visibility is maintained through all tested shells except `ash` and `dash`:

```
Hello World
Found: /usr/bin/ash     version: 0.5.12-2ubuntu1
Found: /usr/bin/bash   version: 5.2.15-2ubuntu1
Found: /usr/bin/dash   version: 0.5.12-2ubuntu1
Found: /usr/bin/ksh     version: 1.0.4-3
Found: /usr/bin/tcsh    version: 6.24.07-1
Found: /usr/bin/zsh     version: 5.9-4
Testing /usr/bin/ash -c 'bash -c fn':
bash: line 1: fn: command not found

Testing /usr/bin/bash -c 'bash -c fn':
Hello World

Testing /usr/bin/dash -c 'bash -c fn':
bash: line 1: fn: command not found

Testing /usr/bin/ksh -c 'bash -c fn':
Hello World

Testing /usr/bin/tcsh -c 'bash -c fn':
Hello World

Testing /usr/bin/zsh -c 'bash -c fn':
Hello World
```

Comment: Interesting! Did you expect the environment variables whether those give a hint?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I did not test environment variable as those are POSIX standard and expected to be inherited with environment unless shell restricts environment like Dash. What is a surprise is that an alien Bash's specific exported function is persisted within the environment through non-Bash shells in-between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment can really only contain strings, so when you use `export -f` in bash, it actually just creates a regular environment variable (with a weird name) and sets it to the text of the function's definition. For example:

```
$ fn(){ printf 'Hello World\n';}
$ export -f fn
$ printenv BASH_FUNC_fn%%
() {  printf 'Hello World\n'
}
```

During bash initialization, it scans the environment for variables with names like this, and converts any that it finds into functions.

Since this is just a regular environment variable (other than its name), it'll persist through various other programs (including shells), unless the programs do something to remove them from the environment. It appears that both dash and ash do this (though I don't have ash handy to test):

```
$ dash -c 'printenv BASH_FUNC_fn%% || echo "not found"'
not found
```

You can see the same effect with other weirdly-named environment variables:

```
$ env test%="still here" bash -c 'printenv test% || echo "not found"'
still here
$ env test%="still here" ksh -c 'printenv test% || echo "not found"'
still here
$ env test%="still here" zsh -c 'printenv test% || echo "not found"'
still here
$ env test%="still here" dash -c 'printenv test% || echo "not found"'
not found
```

Comment: Thank you ! You pinpointed exactly how it works and explained it very nicely.

Comment: So it raise another question. Those environment variable names are illegal shell variable names. How is environment allowed to contain illegal variable names?

Comment: It's just an array in memory; you can put any bytes you want there. The [`putenv`(3) library function](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) probably makes some sanity checks but you can bypass it and write directly to the memory buffer if you know how it's laid out.

Comment: Shell variable names are highly restricted due to shell syntax, but environment variables are an OS feature, completely independent of any shell you might be using, and aren't subject to the same restrictions. Charles Duffy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989263/why-cant-environment-variables-with-dashes-be-accessed-in-bash-4-1-2) has some more info, particularly about what POSIX specifies and/or allows.