# how to use jq ascii_downcase to transform environment key in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jq

Here is the beginning of my docker-compose.yml.

```json
{
  "name": "qualimarc-docker-prod",
  "services": {
    "qualimarc-watchtower": {
      "cpus": 0.5,
      "command": null,
      "container_name": "qualimarc-watchtower",
      "entrypoint": null,
      "environment": {
        "WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP": "true",
        "WATCHTOWER_DEBUG": "false",
        "WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATIONS": "slack",
        "WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_SLACK_CHANNEL": "#notif-qualimarc",
        "WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_SLACK_HOOK_URL": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/TCRRETSQ4/B03QN4MTU3B/",
        "WATCHTOWER_NOTIFICATION_SLACK_IDENTIFIER": "diplotaxis1-prod qualimarc-watchtower",
        "WATCHTOWER_NO_STARTUP_MESSAGE": "true",
        "WATCHTOWER_POLL_INTERVAL": "60",
        "WATCHTOWER_RUN_ONCE": "false",
        "WATCHTOWER_SCOPE": "qualimarc-watchtower-scope",
        "WATCHTOWER_WARN_ON_HEAD_FAILURE": "never"
      },
      "image": "containrrr/watchtower:1.4.0",
      "labels": {
        "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.scope": "qualimarc-watchtower-scope"
      },
      "mem_limit": "3221225472",
      "memswap_limit": "3221225472",
      "networks": {
        "default": null
      },
      "restart": "unless-stopped",
      "volumes": [
        {
          "type": "bind",
          "source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
          "target": "/var/run/docker.sock",
          "bind": {
            "create_host_path": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I try to convert all key environment to lowercase and replacing '*' by '*' like following:

```json
        "watchtower-cleanup": "true",
        "watchtower-debug": "false",
         ....
```

I managed to do the transformation of the key file by doing:

```bash
echo $(docker-compose config --format json) | jq '.services|with_entries(.key|=ascii_downcase)'
```

but it seems to be more complicated to do the same with environment.
It should be something like

```bash
echo $(docker-compose config --format json) | jq '.services|with_entries(.value|with_entries(.key|=ascii_upcase))'
```

but it doesn't work.

Please note that I want to keep the environment variable value to original case.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Isn't using the full path on the LHS doing what you want ? `jq '.services."qualimarc-watchtower".environment|=with_entries(.key|=ascii_downcase)'` [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DhydhGWH3aV)

Comment: ... and if you want to do the `"_"` to `"-"` translation, [`jq '.services."qualimarc-watchtower".environment|=with_entries(.key|=(ascii_downcase|split("_")|join("-")))'`](https://jqplay.org/s/6wxTFaIwFiZ) or [`jq '.services."qualimarc-watchtower".environment|=with_entries(.key|=(ascii_downcase|sub("_";"-";"g")))'`](https://jqplay.org/s/clRuKO3kJBA).

Comment: Using dashes in environment variable names is _often_ a bad idea. Shells are allowed to drop environment variables with names that aren't also valid shell variable names from the environment, and some common ones do so; so if you're going to use such names in a way that's reliable/portable, you need to ensure that there's no shell between the process that creates them and the process that consumes them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992531/14122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [update-assignement `|=`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#update-assignment) on all environment objects:

```bash
docker-compose config --format json | jq '
.services[].environment |= with_entries(
  .key |= (ascii_downcase | gsub("_";"-"))
)
'
```

To handle services without the `environment` key, [suppress errors with `?`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#error-suppression-optional-operator):

```
.services[].environment |= with_entries(
  .key |= (ascii_downcase | gsub("_";"-"))
)?
```

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "qualimarc-docker-prod",
  "services": {
    "qualimarc-watchtower": {
      "cpus": 0.5,
      "command": null,
      "container_name": "qualimarc-watchtower",
      "entrypoint": null,
      "environment": {
        "watchtower-cleanup": "true",
        "watchtower-debug": "false",
        "watchtower-notifications": "slack",
        "watchtower-notification-slack-channel": "#notif-qualimarc",
        "watchtower-notification-slack-hook-url": "https://hooks.slack.com/services/TCRRETSQ4/B03QN4MTU3B/",
        "watchtower-notification-slack-identifier": "diplotaxis1-prod qualimarc-watchtower",
        "watchtower-no-startup-message": "true",
        "watchtower-poll-interval": "60",
        "watchtower-run-once": "false",
        ...
```

Comment: The exact command is `docker-compose config --format json | jq '.services[].environment |= try with_entries(  .key |= (ascii_downcase | gsub("_";"-")))'` . Please correct `.services.[]` into `.services[]`

Comment: The first `|=` was the essential element to exactly get the initial json into the targeted targeted json. Omitting it drops the keys.

Comment: `try` is needed for services that don't contain the non-mandatory environment value.

Comment: @NathanaëlBlanchet `.services.[]` and `.services[]` are equivalent.