how can i fetch variable from a file which is mount file into a shell script during container run
I am trying to fetch variables from a .conf/ini file as environment variables into a Shell script. This file is mounted during container run.
Again once fetched into the shell script I want the variables to be exported.
I tried the below steps.
#!bin/bash
DB_NAME=${env.DB_URL}
export URL=${DB_NAME}

I have passed this DB_URL value in a file and not sure which location do i mount the file to be fetched in the script as env variable.

Please format your code properly. Also I don't know wat you mean by _passing DB_URL value in a file.

${env.DB_URL} is syntactically incorrect. Paste your code into shellcheck, before asking here.

Note that environment variable names just become shell variable names directly -- you don't need a env. prefix to get them out of the environment; it'll be available just as DB_URL.

If you used extract information from ini file and add to associative array bash to make env an associative array loaded from your ini file, then you would be running export URL="${env[DB_URL]}"

shell variable names can contains only letters, numbers and underscore character, so env.something is a wrong name for shell variable (but correct for environment variable).
You can try to parse result of env command in bash using this workaround with grep or other tool (awk/sed), but it is not stable:
DB_NAME="$(env | grep -oP '^env\.DB_URL=\K.*')"

In this command -o option will show only pattern, -P enables perl compatible regexp, \K will remove everything before the value
Another way is to use printenv command:
DB_NAME="$(printenv env.DB_URL)"

I think it is better way, if printenv command exists in your system

Note that some common shells will delete environment variables with names that don't map to shell variables, so this isn't portably functional behavior (even if we ignore that grep -P requires the optional compile-time dependency on libpcre to be enabled to be available even in GNU grep, and isn't generally available on any non-GNU implementations at all that I know of).

...that said, if that is what the OP wants here (I'd be surprised: Several other tools/languages require a env. prefix to access environment variables, and I suspect the OP is coming from one of those), that would make the question duplicative of Accessing environment variables that don't map to valid shell variable names

Moreover, the answer there works correctly with environment variables containing literal newlines, whereas this one can truncate such variables or find spurious results (for an example of the latter, consider export foo=$'hello\nenv.DB_URL=blahblah\netc' -- there's no env.DB_URL variable set at all there, but with naive env versions this answer's env | grep will find a match).

Extended my answer with printenv command

Agreed, that's a better approach -- fixes handling of names with spaces. Doesn't help for cases where the shell deleted the variable at startup (as in those cases it won't show up for child processes even though it is there in Linux's /proc/*/environ), but given the portability hit inherent in that result there's value to an alternative. On which point, maybe add your answer to the question that would (if this interpretation of the question is correct) be a duplicate?

@CharlesDuffy but script have no possibility to delete such variable as they have incorrect name for shells ;)
Also, /proc/*/environ contains only the variables and their status on process startstart (removing or changing value or creating new environment variables not changing environ "file" ), so it is normal behaviour

It's the shell itself, not any script, that does the deletion. Give me a minute to get back to my desk and I'll send you a link.

And the fact that these variables can't be set by a shell script means they have to come from a parent process, so if they exist at all, they'll always be in environ (barring corner cases like loadable modules or folks attaching with a debugger and calling setenv() explicitly).

Here we are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989263/why-cant-environment-variables-with-dashes-be-accessed-in-bash-4-1-2

(Mind, I still think you're just completely misunderstanding the OP's question, and that ${env.DB_URL} is syntax they were trying to use to access the environment variable DB_URL, without any env. in its actual name at all)

See my comment on the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78582182/how-can-i-fetch-variable-from-a-file-which-is-mount-file-into-a-shell-script-dur/78583967?noredirect=1#comment138560330_78582182
